# guava Stopwatch.createStarted() undefined?

Tags: java, eclipse, guava

I'm trying to use `com.google.common.base.Stopwatch` but `Stopwatch.createStarted()` according to Eclipse is undefined. When trying to compile, I also get `error: cannot find symbol` on `createStarted()` (NOT on `Stopwatch` class).

I have `import com.google.common.base.Stopwatch;` at the beginning.

When I write `Stopwatch` in Eclipse, I have the following as proposals after hitting ctrl + space: `class` and `this`. `Stopwatch.this` proposals are: `reset()`, `start()`, `stop()` and many other methods but without the static methods.

The code:

```
import com.google.common.base.Stopwatch;

[...]

Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
```

In maven's pom.xml I have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Show the code you have

Comment: Do you have [Guava version 15](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html#createStarted%28%29) or higher?

Comment: @McDowell I have Guava 17.0 as a dependency in my pom.xml.

Comment: Try it in a single file and show the full code of that file.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have an old version of Guava (< 15.0) on your classpath as well (it could be from another dependency).

Comment: You can check this with `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with project configuration. Probably you:

- have Guava 15< in project path. Please check in project settings.
- if you use Maven then Eclipse could cache sources jar and now show you that info because prefer that jar than jar from maven configuration.

Try to rebuild project form commandline. If it IDE problem it should be ok. If it is a problem with dependencies then commanline compilation will fail.